# Import Python script with relative path

Tags: python, path

I have a script that loads an image from its directory, and I want to be able to import that script from any file, with this script still being able to find its image. Probably clearer that way:

- `A/`

  - `file1.py`
  - `images/img.png`
- `B/`

  - `file2.py`

In `file1.py`:

```
image = load_img("images/img.png")
```

In `file2.py`:

```
import file1
# here, I expect to be able to use file1.image
```

But in file2, the relative path is relative to `B/` directory, and `images/img.png` is therefore not found.

How can I have my `image` variable available, no matter from where I import `file1.py` without writing an absolute path here ? What's the best practice to do so ?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: how about you just use ".." in your path?

Comment: I said "no matter from where I import `file1`". I made 2 directories as an example, but real case is more complex (like a library that could be imported from any project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the directory of "file1.py" and construct the path:

```
# Inside file1.py
import os

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "images/img.png")
image = load_img(filename)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it by default.
u need to use sys.path.insert option to go to that folder then import required file

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../A/')
import file1

print file1.image
```